# Can I push old git flow tags after you've pushed the release

Tags: git, tags

I have been using git flow for a little while but by no means an expert. I am unsure about tags. Before I create a release I run 'git tag --list' and then when I start my release I run 'git flow release start v2.4' - v2.4 being my tag. However, I think I am missing something. When I recently logged into my dev site, the log is up-to-date but the tags are not. I have not pushed tags specifically.

Can I just push all the old tags? Am I missing something with using tags?

Thanks for the help understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push --tags` should push the tags up.

You can read about it with `git help push` at the terminal.